# get id of ul element using class name of li in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I  have the following html code

```
   <ul id="div0">
    <li id="INT" class="demographics">MemberID</li>
    <li id="VARCHAR" class="demographics">Name</li>
    </ul>
   <ul id="div1">
   <li id="INT" class="lab">DOB</li>
   <li id="INT" class="lab">ZipCode</li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="div2">
  <li id="VARCHAR" class="labresult">Payroll</li>
   <li id="INT" class="labresult">DrID</li>
  <ul>
```

in  jquery i want to get the id of ul element using class name of li element,

for example

```
             $('.demographics').click(function(){
                 // here i want the id of ul tag containing class demographics
                  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use this

```
$('.demographics').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).parent('ul').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$('.demographics').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('ul')[0].id;
    console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look for the parent() using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net

```
$(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Comment: can we use the class name instead of using this, like $('.demographics').parent().attr('id');

Comment: Yes, but I would not recommend doing this. You already indicated .demographics so jQuery knows what node you're dealing with. If you ever have to change it to let say ".aplhabetics" you have to change 2 lines. Now only one.

Furthermore, using $(this) allows you to manipulate the selected node, not just any ".demographics" match